# compare two columns value in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, compare, multiple-columns

I have a csv data frame like below, I'd like to compare two column value and generate third column, if value is same will return `True`, not same return `False`, how to compare with pandas python?

```
one two
1   a
2   b
3   a
4   b
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  10
```

Answer (score 4):

You need if values are mixed (`string` and `int`):

```
df['three'] = df.one == df.two
```

But need [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) if values are not mixed - `dtype` of first column is `int` and second is `object` what is obviously `string` and in column `one` are not `NaN` values, because `to_numeric` with parameter `errors='coerce'` return `NaN` for non numeric values:

```
print (pd.to_numeric(df.two, errors='coerce'))
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     5.0
5     6.0
6     7.0
7     8.0
8     9.0
9    10.0
Name: two, dtype: float64

df['three'] = df.one == pd.to_numeric(df.two, errors='coerce')
print (df)
   one two  three
0    1   a  False
1    2   b  False
2    3   a  False
3    4   b  False
4    5   5   True
5    6   6   True
6    7   7   True
7    8   8   True
8    9   9   True
9   10  10   True
```

Faster solution with [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.eq.html):

```
df['three'] = df.one.eq(pd.to_numeric(df.two, errors='coerce'))
print (df)
   one two  three
0    1   a  False
1    2   b  False
2    3   a  False
3    4   b  False
4    5   5   True
5    6   6   True
6    7   7   True
7    8   8   True
8    9   9   True
9   10  10   True
```